# Estou tentando fazer um jogo de "Spock". O código até roda, mas imprime errado. Quando eu escolho "1" ele imprime papel ao inves de pedra :(

Tags: python

```
player_1 = input("Player 1: Qual o seu Nome? ")
player_2 = input("Player 2: Qual o seu Nome? ")
entradasValidas = ('Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura', 'Lagarto', 'Esponja')
print('''Considerando as seguintes escolhas como válidas:
[1] Pedra 
[2] Papel 
[3] Tesoura
[4] Lagarto 
[5] Esponja''')
player_1 = int(input("Player 1: Qual sua Escolha? "))
player_2 = int(input("Player 2: Qual sua Escolha? "))
print("*" * 40)
print("Player_1 Escolheu: {}".format(entradasValidas[player_1]))
print("Player_2 Escolheu: {}".format(entradasValidas[player_2]))
print("*" * 40)
if player_1 == 1: # jogador 1 jogou PEDRA 
    if player_2 == 1:
      print("Temos um Empate!")
    elif player_2 == 2:
      print("O Papel Embrulha a Pedra. O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 3:
      print("A Pedra Esmaga a Tesoura. O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 4:
      print("A Pedra Esmaga o Lagarto. O Jogador 1 Venceu!")
    elif player_2 == 5:
      print("A Esponja VAporiza a Pedra. O Jogador 2 Venceu!")
    else:
      print("Ops! Essa jodada está inválida. Tente novamente!")
```

Comment: Isso porque o índice da tupla começa em zero, então para obter o primeiro elemento precisa fazer `tupla[0]`, ou seja, `entradasValidas[player_1-1]`

Answer (score 0):

Os arrays e tuplas em python (no caso sua variável, `entradasValidas`, é uma tupla) são indexadas por zero, logo você tem que fazer com que a entrada do usuário seja subtraída por 1 ou avisar para o usuário botar o valor 1 para baixo (0 para pedra, 1 para papel e assim por diante).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigada! Agora deu certo S2